# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, runtime-error

I recently got this msg on my site while going thru settings of the plugin SuperSlider-login:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in /home/content/78/9634878/html/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 487**

I m not sure what triggered this msg..I have tried the following:

1. If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini
   If your line shows 32M try 64M:
   `memory_limit = 128M ;` Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
2. If you don't have access to PHP.ini try adding this to an `.htaccess` file:

   `php_value memory_limit 128M`
3. Try adding this line to your wp-config.php file:
   Increasing memory allocated to PHP
   `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');`

But no change..
Also,I had upgraded to WordPress 3.5 a few minutes ago.. Could that affect the site?

Comment: Your memory limit is already 268 MB, so setting it to 128 MB is actually *reducing* it. That is a pretty heavy value to hit, though, and might be a memory leak in the plugin

Comment: Sory,I had changed it to memory_limit=256; The exact amount that it said that is exhausted.

Comment: Instead of increasing the max memory, try to fix the problem causing it to use so much memory in the first place. It's probably a bug in your script.

Comment: Disable the plugin to see if it is the cause and not the WP upgrade. The plugin might have some bad code causing a loop perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

Check and see if you are recursively calling a function:

```
// ---  DON'T DO THIS: ---
function myFunction(){
  $out.=myFunction();
  return $out;
}
```